# Acceptability of Linearized General Relativity with Exact Linear Metrics

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gravitational-waves

Linearized general relativity is typically employed when [gravity is weak, and the metric can be approximated as a perturbation of a (usually flat) background metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearized_gravity). However, for some classes of metrics, such as the [pp-wave spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pp-wave_spacetime), the exact and linearized forms of the vacuum metric are identical, and their Einstein equations contain no non-linear terms. With that in mind, is it then acceptable to apply linearized GR in the exact case?

Comment: What do you mean by "apply linearized GR in the exact case?" If you want exact results, you have to solve the exact Einstein equations. Sometimes, if you assume a lot of symmetry, the exact Einstein equations reduce to a form where you can solve them analytically. OTOH "linearized GR" (to me) sounds like you are applying an approximation and working with a set of equations that approximates but is not identical to to the Einstein equations in some situation. You can only get approximate solutions of Einstein's equations, if you solve equations which are approximations of Einstein's equations.

Comment: What I meant to convey was that when you solve the exact equations, and you solve the linearized equations for these specific spacetimes, you find the same result.

Comment: If the exact equations happen to be linear in some variable, then solving those linear equations is the same as solving the exact equations.

Comment: I see. Then, for that specific case, when you have the exact equations as a set of linear equations, is it acceptable to apply linear theories like gravitomagnetism, etc. to the exact, linear metrics?

Comment: I think gravitomagnetism is normally derived in perturbation theory *without* making particular assumptions about the symmetry of the metric perturbations. On the other hand, pp waves are derived assuming the exact metric has certain symmetries. So, while it's possible you could find some analog of gravitoelectromagnetism in a PP wave solution, I don't think you can just take results from general linearlized perturbations around a Minkowski background and assume they'll apply to a pp wave spacetime. The ultimate way to check though is to look at the pp wave metric.

Comment: I see. To simplify a little, one example of a pp-wave spacetime I was considering was the Bonnor beam, which models an incoherent beam of light. For that metric, the interior and exterior solutions are both linear. When you say, "look at the pp wave metric" what precisely do you mean?

Comment: I'm probably going to wrap up responding on my end, but maybe this discussion will help clarify the issues. What I'm saying is that you have an exact solution (metric) you want to study. If you want to know whether that metric has property X, then (a) relate X to some property of the geometry, eg the Riemann tensor, (b) compute the Riemann tensor from your metric, (c) see if this property holds for your metric. You don't need to use perturbation theory if you know the exact solution. You also can't just assume some perturbative solution derived in a different context applies.